# Use JSON file instead of environment files only for build application in angular 9

Tags: angular

I have Multiple json files like config.dv.json, config.local.json etc, and I need to load these json files based on environments by using single command as ng build --prod command.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use these environment files?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing Angular CLI does is, it replaces environment.ts with the correct environment (e.g. environment.prod.ts).

You could add your config JSON files to your assets in a folder "configs" and name them environment-specific, as stated in your question ("dv.json", "local.json", etc.). Now, in environment.ts you can reference your config like this, for example:

```
export const environment = {
  name: "dev",
  config: "dv"
};
```

Finally, you just need to load your config file based on the environment, e.g. like this:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

this.http.get('./configs/' + environment.config + '.json').pipe(
map((res:any) => {
  let configJson = res.json();
})).subscribe();
```

Comment: where I need to load this config file? can you please provide a example

Comment: depends on where you need it. I'd implement a configservice, which handles the configs as a singleton.